# _All_links_are_underlined_ in high contrast mode

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, accessibility, high-contrast-mode

All links in the page are underlined when using high contrast mode - it does not matter whether it is light or dark.

Here are examples:

A question - notice how the reputation and badges at the top are also underlined:

[image: Screenshot of a question where every link is underlined - title, tags, as well as linked questions on the side, and the user statistics in the top right.]

Another question - this one also has the comments:

[image: Another screenshot of a question where every link is underlined - this time comments are visible and the user who posted them as well as the timestamp is underlined.]

User profile:

[image: Screenshot of a user profile - all section headings, all tags, all links to posts are underlined.]

From what I have seen so far only the footer of the page does not have underlined links.

It is normal convention for links to be underlined on websites. However, this seems *excessive*. It makes reading things like usernames and tags very hard, which is counter to the idea of high contrast mode.

Comment: Can confirm, only started in the last idk, recently :p

Comment: @Nick within the last hour, perhaps. I'm not sure exactly. Might be a bit longer if my browser was using cached styles. It's *definitely* very new. From today. The CSS has an explicit rule to add underlines: `body.theme-highcontrast a, body.theme-highcontrast .s-link { text-decoration:underline }` so it's not random.

Comment: This was an intentional change for high-contrast mode in Stacks 0.72.0 but I'll leave it to the design team to explain why the change was made (I don't actually know why, only that the change was intentional).

Comment: @animuson Appreciate that animuson... unfortunately while it's high contrast it massively hinders readability, will wait to see what design team say.

Comment: It seems quite broken. Look at the "typescript" tag (user profile image, towards the bottom). In general it's the tags, some titles, and usernames that are very hard to read. The user stats at the top also don't seem OK when underlined. Might be intentional but I don't think it's useful right now. I'm debating disabling high contrast mode at the moment. I would definitely do if this is actually what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: This seems more accessible to me. I can't even see the outline around badges in your screenshot.  And in fact, it can be confusing if a username is a link because it's almost the same color as text in some places. (Just remember, these features are mostly for people with worse vision than mine.)

Comment: @Laurel I'm using high contrast mode *because* it lets me see better. It currently does not in several areas. I'm also surprised you cannot see the outline - I can. Even in the smaller screenshots.

Comment: @Laurel That's a fair assessment, unfortunately they then fall down on the consistency, Edit Profile and Profiles in the top right should then also be underlined to differentiate them from the not underlined currently tracked Archaeologist badge. The selected Summary and Activity tabs should be underlined. Nothing in the drop down menus (inbox, achievements, queues, etc.) is underlined... Really they should consider all the links individually and putting underlines on the _appropriate_ ones, not just blindly put them on all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I mean badges not tags. (The tag badges are fine too)

Answer (score 6):

As @animuson states, this was an intentional change. We initially hesitated on underlining links in high contrast mode because it was initially technically difficult to implement, but revisited recently and shipped this change.

[W3C suggests adding underlines to links](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F73.html#F73-procedure) as to not rely on color to distinguish links from other content. It is a tricky compromise because adding anything to text *could* make it less legible, plus it tends to hurt aesthetics by making the design feel a bit busier. With all that said, I think it's a worthwhile compromise since it achieves the goal of making links *extremely* obvious.

> It seems quite broken. Look at the "typescript" tag[…]

The typescript tag has a very visible border because of distinct styling between "badge tags" and plain old "badges". I've found the underline particularly useful on these elements because we can't always rely on a border to visually indicate that you're looking at a link.

> […]only the footer of the page does not have underlined links.

Footer links *should* be underlined but aren't because of a legacy rule that overrides footer anchor `text-decoration: underline`. You found a mistake on our part!

> […]this seems *excessive*.

We have a couple of exceptions for this underlining (I believe pagination elements are an example), so we could swing the pendulum away from nearly *every* link being underlined. There probably are elements where an underline could be removed, but only on elements where some visual differentiator beyond hue can be used to indicate interactivity. Over time, I anticipate this will be finessed and increased adoption of our design system will help us make these sorts of changes with a little more nuance.

Comment: "*The typescript tag has a very visible border because of distinct styling between "badge tags" and plain old "badges".*" this is not at all what I mean by "broken" - [the *text* looks broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0s9.png) the lower part of **y* and the **p** break up the line. And the underline kind of makes **p** resemble an **R** with the extra line there. Or maybe an **o**. The tags in general have smaller font and adding an underline just makes for *a lot* of visual information to process.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification! Can I ask what browser/OS combination you're using? I'm curious to reproduce the issue locally and find some similar instances where the text descenders get muddied with the underlines.

Comment: Firefox 94 on Windows 10. The font family the browser reports is "Inter, sans-serif"

Comment: "Tonight we're gonna format like it's 1999."

Comment: Hi @DanCormier, can this be revisited? Specifically for the case of underscores, which in programming are relatively... common? The underline makes them hard to identify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQMFI.png

Comment: I would say it's excessive for the question tags, because they're already styled to look like buttons (and there are other buttons in the UI, like "Ask Question", which don't have that underline). But otherwise I think it's perfectly reasonable to have that much underlining.